# Azure ACS - IncomingCall event not firing

Tags: azure-communication-services

I'm testing Azure ACS for sending/receiving PSTN calls. Using the Call Automation API, sending calls works, however I have been unable to receive calls. I'm following the instructions available here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/call-automation/incoming-call-notification#receiving-an-incoming-call-notification-from-event-grid

I have three local numbers (Germany) available in my ACS resource. In the Azure portal, all numbers have the features "Make, receive calls".

Using the [Azure-Samples on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-dotnet-quickstarts/tree/callautomation/callautomationQuickStart/CallAutomation_OutboundCalling), I am able to make outbound calls.

I am currently trying to extend the app to handle incoming calls. To that end I have added an Event Grid System Topic resource for my ACS instance, and a subscription which calls a Webhook. The subscription has a WebHook subscription, which filters on IncomingCall events. Upon saving the subscription, I receive the subscription validation event, so my Webhook seems to be working.

For whatever reason, I cannot get the IncomingCall event to fire when I call one of my PSTN numbers. When calling I get the immediate response "The requested subscriber cannot be reached at the moment". I don't see any events being published in the Azure portal, and my Webhook is never called. It seems as if the event is simply not firing - and I cannot figure out why.

Code sample of my webhook:

```
app.MapPost("/incomingCall", async (EventGridEvent[] eventGridEvents, ILogger<Program> logger) =>
{
    foreach (var eventGridEvent in eventGridEvents)
    {
        if (eventGridEvent.TryGetSystemEventData(out object eventData))
        {
            if (eventData is SubscriptionValidationEventData subscriptionValidationEventData) // received!
            {
                var responseData = new SubscriptionValidationResponse
                {
                    ValidationResponse = subscriptionValidationEventData.ValidationCode
                };
                return Results.Ok(responseData);
            }

            if (eventData is AcsIncomingCallEventData incomingCallEventData) // not received
            {
                Response<AnswerCallResult> answerCallResult =
                    await callAutomationClient.AnswerCallAsync(incomingCallEventData.IncomingCallContext, new Uri(callbackUriHost + "/api/callbacks"));
                logger.LogInformation($"Answered a call: {answerCallResult.Value.CallConnection.CallConnectionId}");
                return Results.Ok();
            }
        }
    }

    return Results.StatusCode(500); // doesn't come here either
});
```

Any insight here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had the same issue with Swedish numbers. Add a UK number and see if that fires events.